# Turn a formatted PowerShell hash table/array definition into a single line (and vice versa) via hot key in Visual Studio Code

Tags: string, powershell, replace, yaml

In Visual Studio Code I am trying to work out a way to convert a piece of PowerShell (which defines a collection of hash tables and arrays) into a single line of code, and also a way to perform the same operation but the other way (i.e. take a single line and make it more readable).  I need to do this because the YAML variable I am defining needs to be done on a single line (the `PowerShell` gets passed to another `PowerShell` script via this variable).

So, for example, I need to be able to turn:

```sh
@{
    TestData = @{
        Connections = @(
            @{
                ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';
                SourceVmName  = 'D3ZUKS342APP01';
                Targets       = @(
                    @{
                        DestinationVmName          = 'D3ZUKS342SQL01';
                        DestinationVmResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';
                        DestinationPort            = 1433;
                        Status                     = 'Reachable'
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    };
    IPFlows  = @(
        @{
            ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';
            TargetVmName  = 'D3ZUKS342SQL01';
            InboundFlows  = @(
                @{
                    Description     = 'Application Server D3ZUKS342APP01';
                    Protocol        = 'TCP';
                    LocalPorts      = 1433;
                    RemoteIpAddress = '10.124.36.132';
                    RemotePort      = 0;
                }
            );
            OutboundFlows = @()
        }
    )
}
```

into:

```sh
@{TestData = @{Connections = @(@{ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';SourceVmName= 'D3ZUKS342APP01';Targets = @(@{DestinationVmName= 'D3ZUKS342SQL01';DestinationVmResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';DestinationPort= 1433;Status = 'Reachable' })});IPFlows = @(@{ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';TargetVmName= 'D3ZUKS342SQL01';InboundFlows= @(@{Description = 'Application Server D3ZUKS342APP01';Protocol= 'TCP';LocalPorts= 1433;RemoteIpAddress = '10.124.36.132';RemotePort= 0;});OutboundFlows = @()})}}
```

And more importantly, do the same in reverse (i.e. take the single line and make it readable/editable). Ideally I'd love to be able to do both by mapping a hotkey to both operations.

The multi line > single line seems easier - a regex replace of \s+( ) with nothing, followed by a replace of carriage returns with nothing, but how can I map that to a hotkey?

The single line > multi line seems much harder :( I have searched for an extension that might help, but to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions, either native Visual Studio Code functionality or an extension that I could use?

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to do this in VSCode instead of during execution of your script.

Comment: Hi zett42. The PowerShell data is being passed to an Azure YAML pipeline task, which in turn runs some more PowerShell with the data above passed as a parameter, via a YAML variable.  But YAML variable definition only allows data like this to be defined on one line :(

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not understand why you need this either, specific to the request for a oneliner: you might use this [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) cmdlet to rebuild your expression from an object using several expansion levels:

```
$Object = @{
    TestData = @{ ...
```

```
# Oneliner
$Object | ConvertTo-Expression -Expand 0
@{IPFlows = ,@{ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01'; TargetVmName = 'D3ZUKS342SQL01'; InboundFlows = ,@{Description = 'Application Server D3ZUKS342APP01'; RemoteIpAddress = '10.124.36.132'; RemotePort = 0; Protocol = 'TCP'; LocalPorts = 1433}; OutboundFlows = @()}; TestData = @{Connections = ,@{ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01'; SourceVmName = 'D3ZUKS342APP01'; Targets = ,@{DestinationVmName = 'D3ZUKS342SQL01'; DestinationPort = 1433; DestinationVmResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01'; Status = 'Reachable'}}}}

# Compressed
$Object | ConvertTo-Expression -Expand -1
@{IPFlows=,@{ResourceGroup='d3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';TargetVmName='D3ZUKS342SQL01';InboundFlows=,@{Description='Application Server D3ZUKS342APP01';RemoteIpAddress='10.124.36.132';RemotePort=0;Protocol='TCP';LocalPorts=1433};OutboundFlows=@()};TestData=@{Connections=,@{ResourceGroup='d3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';SourceVmName='D3ZUKS342APP01';Targets=,@{DestinationVmName='D3ZUKS342SQL01';DestinationPort=1433;DestinationVmResourceGroup='d3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01';Status='Reachable'}}}}

# Expanded (to any level)
$Object | ConvertTo-Expression # -Expand to any level
@{
    IPFlows = ,@{
            ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01'
            TargetVmName = 'D3ZUKS342SQL01'
            InboundFlows = ,@{
                    Description = 'Application Server D3ZUKS342APP01'
                    RemoteIpAddress = '10.124.36.132'
                    RemotePort = 0
                    Protocol = 'TCP'
                    LocalPorts = 1433
                }
            OutboundFlows = @()
        }
    TestData = @{Connections = ,@{
                ResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01'
                SourceVmName = 'D3ZUKS342APP01'
                Targets = ,@{
                        DestinationVmName = 'D3ZUKS342SQL01'
                        DestinationPort = 1433
                        DestinationVmResourceGroup = 'd3zuks-bussvc-342-brimig-rgrp01'
                        Status = 'Reachable'
                    }
            }}
}
```